# agregar nueva fila a tabla en php

Tags: php, html, mysql, php7

Resulta que estoy haciendo un llamado a la base de datos, con el fin de poder sacar unos registros esos registros los recorro mediante la funcion foreach envevido en un , todo me funciona bien: el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
<table border = "1"><thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">*</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Concepto</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Saldo Inicial</th>
                        <th class="text-center">*mes*</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody><tr><td>11</td><td>110505</td><td class="text-right">4,186,295.40</td><td class="text-right">-5,173,740.00</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>110510</td><td class="text-right">1,550,000.00</td><td class="text-right">700,000.00</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>111005</td><td class="text-right">46,384,753.77</td><td class="text-right">3,173,347.00</td></tr><tr><td>11</td><td>112010</td><td class="text-right">62,530,659.79</td><td class="text-right">-7,289,764.00</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>130505</td><td class="text-right">2,054,821,048.47</td><td class="text-right">196,915,758.00</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>131010</td><td class="text-right">3,540,489,179.26</td><td class="text-right">429,679,214.00</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>131020</td><td class="text-right">73,786,179.00</td><td class="text-right">-190,122,075.00</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>132505</td><td class="text-right">236,031,855.52</td><td class="text-right">42,472,058.00</td></tr><tr><td>13</td><td>138095</td><td class="text-right">100,603,062.00</td><td class="text-right">4,145,212.00</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>159205</td><td class="text-right">-11,976,889.00</td><td class="text-right">-347,175.00</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>159215</td><td class="text-right">-19,502,772.00</td><td class="text-right">-1,508,445.00</td></tr><tr><td>15</td><td>159220</td><td class="text-right">-122,900,973.00</td><td class="text-right">-7,706,684.00</td></tr><tr><td>17</td><td>170595</td><td class="text-right">25,769,596.00</td><td class="text-right">-814,792.00</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Este codigo solo es para mostrar la tabla (html)

con php es el siguiente :

```
<?php

            echo "<table class=\"table table-sm\">";
            echo "<thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class ='text-center'>*</th>
                        <th class ='text-center'>Concepto</th>
                        <th class ='text-center'>Saldo Inicial</th>
                        <th class ='text-center'>*mes*</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";


            foreach($datos['datosXactivos'] as $clave => $datoActivo):
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$datoActivo->grupo."</td>"; //Este es el grupo que identifica.
                    echo "<td>".$datoActivo->subcuenta."</td>";
                    echo "<td class ='text-right'>".number_format($datoActivo->saldo_inicial,2)."</td>";
                    echo "<td class = 'text-right'>".number_format($datoActivo->saldo_final,2)."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
            endforeach;

            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Lo que intento hacer es como ustedes observan la columna de concepto tiene un consecutivo donde los dos primeros digitos hacen un grupo 11 - 13 - 15 -17.

Lo que deseo hacer es que cada vez que termine un grupo ejemplo los 4 primeros campos me agregue otra fila siguiente con una descricion que diga total y la suma de los valores del campo *mes*

Lo he intentado de muchas formas, pero no sé como agregar una columna nueva con eso cada vez que termina un grupo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Cada "grupo" esta compuesto de dos números? o como puedes estar seguro de la subcuenta cuales números representan al grupo? `11` - `13` - `15` - `17`

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, si en efecto hay otro campo que no llamé ahí, es "grupo", ya actualizo la tabla.

Comment: Listo, en efecto es campo * que identifica el grupo, lo que deseo es que cuando cambie ejemplo de 11 a 13 coloque una fila adicional entre ellas con el total de la columna *mes*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre utilizar dos variables, una para comparar entre grupos y otra para acumular el valor de interés.

```
<?php

    echo "<table class=\"table table-sm\">";
    echo "<thead>
            <tr>
                <th class ='text-center'>*</th>
                <th class ='text-center'>Concepto</th>
                <th class ='text-center'>Saldo Inicial</th>
                <th class ='text-center'>*mes*</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";

    $acum = 0;  //variable para acumular el valor
    $grupo = -1;  //grupo inicial por defecto
    $total = 0;
    foreach($datos['datosXactivos'] as $clave => $datoActivo):
        $total += $datoActivo->saldo_final;
        if ($grupo === -1):
             $grupo = $datoActivo->grupo;  //asigno el primer grupo
             $acum += $datoActivo->saldo_final;  //acumulo saldo
        else if ($grupo === $datoActivo->grupo):
             $acum += $datoActivo->saldo_final;  //acumulo saldo cuando el grupo sea igual
        else:
             echo "<tr>";
                 echo "<td colspan='3'>Total</td>";  //Cuando se cambia de grupo se imprime el total
                 echo "<td>".$acum."</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
             $acum = $datoActivo->saldo_final; //Se reinicia el valor en el del item actual
             $grupo = $datoActivo->grupo; //Se guarda el nuevo grupo
        endif;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$datoActivo->grupo."</td>"; //Este es el grupo que identifica.
        echo "<td>".$datoActivo->subcuenta."</td>";
        echo "<td class ='text-right'>".number_format($datoActivo->saldo_inicial,2)."</td>";
        echo "<td class = 'text-right'>".number_format($datoActivo->saldo_final,2)."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    endforeach;
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>Total</td>";  //Al salir del ciclo se imprime el ultimo total
        echo "<td>".$acum."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td colspan='3'>Total todos los grupos</td>";
        echo "<td>".$total."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Grande!!!, me sirivio mucho, muchas gracias. quedo perfecto.

Comment: Hola, que pena nuevamente, ¿Sabes de casualidad, como colocar una ultima fila con la suma total de todas la variable $acum? y que está se imprima al final de la tabla.

Comment: Saludos, edite la respuesta

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por responder, pues según veo si tiene la logica para funcionar, pero me da un valor muy alejado de la suma de los totales. :(, y probe de otra forma colocando $total_inicial += $acum; en el else, en la parte inferior del echo "</tr>"; y me imprime el total sumado, pero el ultimo total no lo toma, y pues queda faltando ese valor para que de el valor correcto.

Comment: faltaba el símbolo de `+` en `$total = $datoActivo->saldo_final;`

Comment: Hola, lastimosamente a mi no me funcionó, pero mira, modifiqué el codigo y así si me funciona, pero... ¿Crees que está bien?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90420/agregar-nueva-fila-a-tabla-en-php entra al chat